# import matlab trained cnn into opencv dnn module

Tags: matlab, opencv

Is it possible to convert a trained convolutional neural network saved as .mat into a .pb format?

I was thinking to import it in opencv using cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow()

Are there any alteratives, o I just should retrain the network directly in tensorflow or keras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found about Open Neural Network Exchange.

You can simply save the network from matlab using exportONNXNetwork(net,filename) and load the network inside opencv using cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX()